# Debug LED code off, no speaker sound

Tags: boot, debug, post, led

Any idea, why my new mainboard is not showing the post code / does not beep at all after start ? The cpu cooler is spinning. Only the audio light is on. I attached  the 2 connectors power and cpu. The psu cooler is also spinning.

The question is. What does it mean ? What do i need to see some code ? Only the cpu ? Or why isn't  it beeping at all. Could it be a faulty psu ? Or mobo..

Config : msi z97 gaming  5
Intel i5
Evga 1600 W

Thank you :)

[image: mainboard]

Answer (score 0):

The newer motherboards have a speaker adapter that you have to plug in near where you've drawn the circle, which might be why you arent getting any beeps.

Also you might need ram to post, not sure how that affects the POST led though. Check the 4/8pin CPU connector isnt a PCI-E connector & try removing the cmos battery/clearing cmos to see if you can get the LED to light up.